# Turn off Apple IIe sound

Tags: apple-ii, applesoft-basic

Is there a way to disable sound output on the Apple IIe from Applesoft Basic?  Can't seem to find this in any of the documentation or online.

Update:  Found this

From http://www.calormen.com/jsbasic/reference.html

> `POKE 49200,0` — toggle speaker (no-op)

But that doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case, to "toggle" the speaker means to move it from one position to the other. To make a sound, you repeatedly toggle the speaker (by poking that address) at a particular speed to make a sound of a particular frequency.

There is no way to turn off this functionality using software. The easiest way is to pull the jumper connecting the speaker to the motherboard.

Comment: It depends on who is accessing the speaker, though.  The corresponding peek or poke can be removed or redirected to achieve silence.

Comment: Yeah, I remember we often had to pull the jumper as the Apple II cases seemed to reverberate badly at *exactly* the frequencies the speaker put out. This was like someone scratching their fingernails down a blackboard :-) In the end, we did a school project that "extended" the speaker into a separate enclosure, less prone to painful effects.